# import Multiple records from csv file into sqlite3 database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, csv, import, sqlite

Iam working on a app which needs huge to be stord in database and display it later, but problem is that how to insert that much data in database , i use .csv file to import data from file and store it in table ,Every thing is working fine but only one Row has been inserted in dataBase , any one have any idea how to insert multiple records in databse,

For Information Iam using Terminal for sqlite3,

Comment: Hope you're splitting the values from the CSV file.

Comment: @Sahil what you mean by spilt?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.import file table` to load large file into the table from terminal, your file and table needs to be organized properly so that they have same columns.

Also you can do search and replace in text editor and then import file with `.read filename` command.

Type `.help` in terminal when in sqlite console for list of the commands available.

Comment: iam following the same syntax first create table then .seperator ,    and in last .import file.csv tablename but only one row is inserted...

Comment: You need to set separator with .separator "," check here for more info http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles

Comment: i set seperators as you mentioned but still same

Comment: Then you can try to replace commas with new lines in some text editor that supports macro and try to import them again. How big file is it? I have imported 415 000 rows without problem